# TortoiseSVN and .svn folder using a symbolic link

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revert

My company uses TortoiseSVN internally to keep our files updated. The .svn folder for the project I have is massive (250GB) and as such I had to move it off to an external HDD. I created a symbolic link to the new location so that TortoiseSVN 'should' still continue to work.

I managed to run a clean-up, but when I tried to revert a file, it gave me an error 'Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with (file)" and "Can't move (tmp file) to ... (original file): The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive". I found that this error is caused by Windows not letting a file be renamed while it is being moved. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Can you use a sparse checkout or check out only a subdirectory of the repository so that you only have the files you *need* for your operations? IOW, do are you *required* to have everything checked out that you do?

Answer (score 0):

Found this wonderful explanation in Internet.

> Subversion, during normal operations, has to atomically rename (and
> move) a file from somewhere in the .svn/ directory to its expected
> location in the working copy. Windows can't do that if the source and
> target of the rename are on different volumes, that's what the error
> message is telling you. It's the move to a different volume
> that fails, not the renaming of the file.
>
> Subversion assumes that it is possible to atomically move a file from the .svn directory to the working copy's checked out files.  That would not possible when the .svn directory is on a different drive / filesystem.
>
> The integrity of the working copy
> relies on atomic renames.

In my case I moved only one subfolder of local repository, not the .svn folder. But the issue is the same, once source .svn folder and destination folder end up to be on a separate disks, atomic file move fails.

There is no option B but to move the folder back to the same disk. You can try to reduce size of your .svn folder by doing 'Clean Up' with 'Vacuum Pristine Copies' flag on.
Or grab a bigger disk.